# Summarising multiple columns across multiple functions by group

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I write these two code together into one instead of having them separate? They work well but I would like to have them into one code. That is, have the total number of production and their average by task and department.

```
df %>%
    group_by(task, department) %>%                     
    summarise(across(.cols = c(production),
                  .fns = sum,
                   na.rm=T))                                     

df %>%
    group_by(task, department) %>%
    summarise(across(.cols = c(hours),
                     .fns = mean,                          
                     na.rm=T))
```

Comment: I think you code here will give the sum for both columns. I want to sum the production column and get the mean for the hours column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>%
    group_by(task, department) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(hours), sum = sum(production))
```

Comment: It's still showing mean and sum for production and mean and sum for hours

Comment: I got it! It works now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it okay to ask you more question here?

Comment: Best to open a new question.